# Method for finding Length of intervals between 'True' values in a Boolean Array (Efficient method)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

Say you have a boolean/binary array in Numpy called 'a', where 'a' is a sequence of 0s and 1s (or equivalently True/False). I want to find the distances between the 1s in 'a'.

Eg. `a = [1,**0,0**,1,**0**,1,**0,0,0,0,0**,1]`. Output = `[2,1,5]`

What is the most efficient way to evaluate this in Numpy Python? The actual dataset is of the order of 1,000,000 binary values.

Comment: What if there are 2 `1s` in sequence?

Comment: I would assume the output would say '0'.

Comment: Do you care about the distance between successive ones (i.e. which would be zero), or do you only care about the distance when there are zeros in-between?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a numpy way of getting the result:

```
np.diff(np.where(np.array(a)>0))-1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
output = []
i = 0
space = 0
for ii in a:
  if a[i] == 1:
    output.append(space)
    space = 0
  elif a[i] == 0:
    space += 1
  i += 1
print(output)
```

This gives a zero at the beginning, but otherwise is exactly what you want.

Comment: This works, but is there a more efficient way using numpy functions?

Comment: @PhthonNerd  With a = a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], this returns [2, 1].  Is this correct or should it be [1]?

Comment: Depends. Ask Saptarshi.